# Most commented posts by time period (last 12h, last 24h and etc)

Tags: php, database, mysql

I have this code which works great.

```
 <?php 
      $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 25"); // NUMBER OF POSTS
         foreach ($result as $topten) {
             $postid = $topten->ID;
             $title = $topten->post_title;
             $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
             if ($commentcount != 0) {
      ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>"><span class="tags"> <?php echo $title ?></span></a>
   
   <?php } } ?>
```

Now it displays (order) the most popular posts by comment count (ALL-TIME).

I know that WordPress understands command 'period':

```
   period=1hourago
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the above code working with the period, so that I could define:

24hoursago

or

12hoursago

and so on...

I know I need to somehow integrate this into code:

```
 'date_query' => [
        [
           
        ]
    ],
```

But I can't seem to find a way of putting all together.

I saw the idea from: https://www.bitochat.com

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to get the posts that were commented within the last xx hours, e.g. 12 hours, then try one of the following:

Note though, I'm selecting only published posts (`post_status = 'publish'`) and of the `post` type (`post_type = 'post'`).

*And just replace the value of `$hours` with your preferred number of hours.*

- Using [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

  ```php
  $hours = 12;

  $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT p.comment_count, p.ID, p.post_title
          FROM $wpdb->posts p
          INNER JOIN $wpdb->comments c ON c.comment_post_ID = p.ID
      WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
          AND p.post_status = 'publish'
          AND ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, c.comment_date, NOW() ) <= %d )
      GROUP BY p.ID
      ORDER BY p.comment_count DESC
      LIMIT 0, 25
  ", $hours ) );
  ```
- Or calculate the date and time of xx hours ago and use `comment_date >= <date-time xx hours ago>`.

  ```php
  $hours = 12;

  $timestamp = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  $date_ago = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp - $hours * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

  $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT p.comment_count, p.ID, p.post_title
          FROM $wpdb->posts p
          INNER JOIN $wpdb->comments c ON c.comment_post_ID = p.ID
      WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
          AND p.post_status = 'publish'
          AND c.comment_date >= %s
      GROUP BY p.ID
      ORDER BY p.comment_count DESC
      LIMIT 0, 25
  ", $date_ago ) );
  ```

Comment: hey Sally, thanks for your effort. I have updated my original post so that I could show the code. Could you please take a look at. Sorry I'm completely new, so php it's like creating a new bike for me.

Comment: Try using `get_posts()` - in your code, change the `$query = new WP_Query(` to `$posts = get_posts(` and use `foreach ( $posts` in place of `foreach ( $query->posts`. Does it work?

Comment: no :( it displays blank. The interesting part is that when I change 12 hours ago to 80 hours ago, then it displays the same posts as my original code. In other words, all-time posts (which were also made over a month ago) sorted by most comments.

Comment: I have made a few comments just recently, changed to 4hours ago, but it doesn't show those post titles. Blank.

Comment: anyway, thanks for your help. I think I have found a solution with Most Popular Posts WP plugin. Just had to edit  some formatting. Thanks again Sally.

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood the question!  And I could edit the answer with the correct code, if you want. But if you prefer use the plugin, then I'd delete my answer. :)

Comment: You can edit it, I will accept and upvote it. Maybe someone else will find it helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you for that and I've just updated my answer. Would you mind helping me test the code there - just use it in place of your `$wpdb->get_results()` in the question? And hopefully this time I got it correct..

Comment: Worked perfectly! thanks.